# Crawling App Store

Tags: url, store, rating, web-crawler

How would I go about crawling the information in iTunes Preview for a mass amount of apps? I'm trying to gather the number of ratings on many apps, but I can't find a way to input the correct URL for each one considering there is a random App ID I have to use for each one.